# What would be the most appropriate distance metric for percentage/ratio data?

Tags: distance, percentage, ratio, scipy, dissimilarity

I have a matrix where each row is an observation (i), each column is a feature (j), and each value is the ratio the feature j is complete in observation i. That is, the values are floats that range from 0.0 - 1.0

I'm looking through the distance measures in SciPy and I'm not sure which one would be best for this type of data.

**Does anyone have any insight on a (pairwise) distance metric that is designed to handle such a data type?**

My desired end results is to have a symmetric distance matrix of observations.